# sorting alphanumeric values based on characters present in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

my values in the column are like

```
001aka,
004heh,
002kol,
007nam,
003wom,
005emn,
006sup
```

adding order by clause give values

```
001aka,
002kol,
003wom,
004heh,
005emn,
006sup,
007nam
```

but i want the values to be sorted on the characters present rather than the numeric values

desired output:

```
001aka,
005emn,
004heh,
002kol,
007nam,
006sup,
003wom
```

Answer (score 1):

How about sorting using substring function--

```
select * from test order by substr(column,4,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a high performance solution you need to split this field and add an extra index field to the table to save the splited text. You can save both column values and substring values while inserting and updating. Then sort by the index column.

Original column will hold "001aka" and index column will hold "aka"

Pure sql Solution will reduce performance if you have a large table.